# How to save (serialize) MATLAB variables to a byte string?

Tags: matlab

Ideally this would be using the same format as the [save](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) command (.mat file), but instead of writing to disk directly, it would write it to data in memory.

The reason is I need to access the saved data directly to implement a custom hashing method on the variable, and have no need to write it to disk in order to achieve this, and would rather not go through the administratively-heavy option of creating a ram disk through ramfs.

Comment: `save` might not be a good option. The output differs depending on the MATLAB version, but not sure if this is even relevant for you. What kind of variables are we talking about? Just basic stuff like for example a list of doubles? Structs? Objects?

Comment: I see your point, but I'd actually be OK with the version of MATLAB invalidating the object in my particular case (the idea being that any software updates may influence results, however unlikely). I need fairly general support, which is why the (intermediate) output of `save` seems like a good option. E.g., nested structs, cells, arrays. I could probably do without java objects in this particular case.

Comment: Have you considered something like `memmapfile`? It still creates a file at beginning, but later it works as memory access with better performance.

Comment: @XiangruiLi I didn't know about that function, so it is good to know about. But, I was hoping to avoid the initial write. If I have to, I could potentially use ramfs on linux, but am hoping to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Got this answered at [MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/534528-how-to-save-serialize-matlab-variables-to-a-byte-string) by Mohammad Sami:

> There is an undocumented function called `getByteStreamFromArray` which converts a matlab object to bytestream.
>
> To convert it back use the opposite function `getArrayFromByteStream`.